# Progress bar during operation in console application

Tags: c++, visual-c++, encryption

I started working on an encryption application but I seemed to greatly over think how I would get it to show a progress bar as it worked.

the task is simple lSize is the total size od the files being encrypted.

With the following loop in C++

```
//********** Open file **********
FILE * inFile = fopen (argv[1], "rb");
fseek(inFile , 0 , SEEK_END);
unsigned long lSize = ftell(inFile);
rewind(inFile);
unsigned char *text = (unsigned char*) malloc (sizeof(unsigned char)*lSize);
fread(text, 1, lSize, inFile);
fclose(inFile);

//*********** Encypt ************
unsigned char aesKey[32] = {
    /* Hiding this for now */
};

unsigned char *buf;

aes256_context ctx;
aes256_init(&ctx, aesKey);

for (unsigned long i = 0; i < lSize/16; i++) {
    buf = text + (i * 16);
    aes256_decrypt_ecb(&ctx, buf);
}

aes256_done(&ctx);
//******************************************************
```

I was wondering how I could display the progress for the for loop while it works.

I know I need to calculate how much is done so far but I do not know how to do so.

Comment: I may be missing something obvious, but why not simply clear and print whatever you want to see in the console and use 'I' or 'X' a number of times to show the bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is multi-threading. Here is some sample source for a progress bar (from: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/future/future/)

```
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <future>         // std::async, std::future
#include <chrono>         // std::chrono::milliseconds

// a non-optimized way of checking for prime numbers:
bool is_prime (int x) {
   for (int i=2; i<x; ++i) if (x%i==0) return false;
   return true;
}

int main ()
{
   // call function asynchronously:
   std::future<bool> fut = std::async (is_prime,444444443); 

   // do something while waiting for function to set future:
   std::cout << "checking, please wait";
   std::chrono::milliseconds span (100);
   while (fut.wait_for(span)==std::future_status::timeout)
     std::cout << '.';

   bool x = fut.get();     // retrieve return value

   std::cout << "\n444444443 " << (x?"is":"is not") << " prime.\n";

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could this be purposed for a fixed bar as well?

Comment: In order to have a fixed bar you will have to know about how long  it will take to complete the task.